# is there a benefit to starting a neural networks node values randomly?

Tags: neural-network

Is it better to have all node values start at `0`  or just make them random between 0 and 1? For example, starting at 0 would be more consistent, but randomly they could approach the correct value faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other mentioned network initialization is extremely important and can decide if your network will converge or not, how fast it will converge etc.

There are quite a few initialization schemes in the literature and more coming up every so often.
You can see an extended discussion of the schemes and what I discuss below in the [MIT Deep Learning text book](https://github.com/HFTrader/DeepLearningBook).

---

When discussing random initializations you need to consider a) what distribution you will sample from b) what is the scale or range you will sample from.

Regarding the distribution, you will typically use a either a uniform or gaussian distribution, and the choice between them doesn't seem to have a large effect.

However the scale or range of the random weights **does** have a very large impact on your results.

In the end it is very dependent on your architectural choices but two very common strategies to select the ranges are:

[image: Formula]

and

[image: Formula]

where `m` is the number of inputs to the layer and `n` the number of outputs.

**Note** that this is not necessarily the "perfect" initialization that you can choose and you should experiment with a few and find the one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you start all parameters at zero, then since a neural network is composed of linear parts, all of them will output zero as well, and the final neural network output will be zero. The gradients will also be zero and the network will not learn.

That doesn't sound good.

That's why we initialize neural network parameters at random, this is one way to "break the symmetry". It is usually initialized in the [-1, 1] range, but this is not the only way. Glorot's method for example scales this range by 1 / (inputs + outputs) of a neuron, and there are other methods, but definitely all of them use random initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Many computational structures are very sensitive to initial conditions.  Varying the initial conditions is a great way to explore the solution space to find more global maxima.  You should set them randomly, different for each run.

Comment: Also beware of vanishing gradients. E.g. the logistic function's derivative is `d_sigma(x)=s(x)*(1-s(x))`, which vanishes at both high and low values of x. Thus backpropagation in the gradient direction will not work, as the gradient has vanished. This is an example of how important initial conditions are.

Comment: I read somewhere that they should be random between `-1 and 1` with a mean of 0 (approx). Is that correct, or is there a better way?